# Process hangs when communicating with an interactive program

Tags: python, subprocess, interactive

I have created a simple `echo.py` like this:

```
import sys

while True:
    s = sys.stdin.readline()
    s = s.strip('\n')
    if s == 'exit':
        break

    sys.stdout.write("You typed: %s\n" % s)
```

It works well on the terminal.

And another program to interact with `echo.py` named `main.py`

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'echo.py'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    proc.stdin.write(b'Hello\n')
    proc.stdin.flush()
    print(proc.stdout.readline())

    proc.stdin.write(b'Hello World\n')
    proc.stdin.flush()
    print(proc.stdout.readline())

    proc.terminate()
```

The `main.py` just hangs forever.
The thing is if I create subprocess with `['python', '-i']`, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `sys.stdout.flush()` to `echo.py`.  Buffering works differently if you run the process with `Popen` instead of the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the while loop.. You're opening a subprocess, writing to it and flushing, and it does all that, but never finishes readline() because of the loop.